# Hyperledger fabric: fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{"code":20,"message":"Authorization failure"}]]

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to create a new identity with this command: composer `identity issue -c admin@siemens-network -f administrator1.card -u Administrator1 -a "resource:org.siemens.Administrator#001"`

But I get the following output:

```
Issue identity and create Network Card for: Administrator1

✖ Issuing identity. This may take a few seconds...
Error: fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{"code":20,"message":"Authorization failure"}]]
Command failed
```

I already restarted the fabric but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted all cards, restarted the network and reimported all cards. Now it's working

Answer (score 1):

Please check `admin@siemens-network` card has existed

```
composer card list
```

If you do not have this card, access the folder containing the createPeerAdminCard.sh file and run

```
./createPeerAdminCard.sh
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: oh. I also encountered this error before and now it's fine.